# Attribute Targets C# - How to port the code with attribute targets into Java?

Tags: c#, java, porting

First of all, we are talking about [Keepass](http://keepass.info/) here.
The file in question is: `KeePass-2.19-Source\KeePass\Native\NativeMethods.cs`

The code.. well, is the file itself. But here is a snippet:

```
    [DllImport("KeePassLibC32.dll", EntryPoint = "TransformKey256")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool TransformKey32(IntPtr pBuf256,
        IntPtr pKey256, UInt64 uRounds);
```

Now the problem is, that Java doesn't support [Attribute Targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177223.aspx). How can I port the file into Java?
Is it possible? If so... how?

Comment: AFAIK Java doesn't support P/Invoke either, so the point is moot... (you can achieve the same result with JNI, but the code can't be translated directly from C#)

Comment: :-/ | If no solution is available, just post that as an answer. I'll accept it and will start coding.

Comment: The way to port attribute targets into Java is to port them as "annotation" targets... if that is what you need to know, I already provided the answer, if, on the other hand you want to re-implement DllImport PInvoke functionality, then maybe you should change the title and text of your question...

Comment: @Luxspes - I'll just remove the file from the project and re-implement the features it relies on. Like detecting Caps Lock's state and the input keyboard language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java **does** support attribute targets (but they are "annotation" targets): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html

But that will not help you much... unless you plan to invent your own DllImport that somehow uses JNI... throught something like JSR-299

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Java doesn't support P/Invoke either, so attribute targets won't help you there... You should be able to achieve the same result with JNI, but this code can't be translated literally from C#.